# Strapi photos disappeared

Tags: mongodb, heroku, strapi

I am using Heroku for deploy, mongoDB Atlas as Database and Strapi as Headless CMS. Heroku is already working with hobby Dyno. Yesterday I added some data into my database with some pictures and it was working fine but after 24 hours my Strapi doesn't display the pictures, I checked my DB and seems like I still have documents with photos. So if you encountered this problem before where is the problem and how did you sol it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku will delete all files stored on the server after each restart.

Check on documentation:

https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/troubleshooting.html#why-is-my-app-s-database-and-uploads-resetting-on-paas

> For file uploads, you will need to use one of the 3rd party providers such as Cloudinary or AWS S3.

For AWS S3 you can check the docs using a provider:

https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/upload.html#using-a-provider

For more providers you can search on npm:

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=strapi-provider-upload-&ranking=popularity